# Navigate WebBrowser from list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

when I launch this program I get in MessageBox only **http://www.google.com**, but
I should get **http://www.yahoo.com** and after that **http://www.google.com**. So, where is a problem? So, can you help me fix this problem? Thank you :)

There is a XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication19.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800">
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Button Name="btn" Content="Navigate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="697,223,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    <Button Name="shower" Content="getValues" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="697,262,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="shower_Click"/>
</Grid></Window>
```

and there is C# short code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using mshtml;

namespace WpfApplication19
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<string> list = new List<string>();
        private List<string> arrOfAdresses = new List<string>();
        private WebBrowser thisIsWeb;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            list.Add("http://www.yahoo.com");
            list.Add("http://www.google.com");
            thisIsWeb = new WebBrowser();
            thisIsWeb.Width = thisIsWeb.Height = 400;
            this.grid.Children.Add(thisIsWeb);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string s in list)
            {
                thisIsWeb.Navigate(s);
                thisIsWeb.LoadCompleted += OnthisIsWebCompleted;
            }
        }

        private void OnthisIsWebCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser bro = sender as WebBrowser;
            this.arrOfAdresses.Add(bro.Source.ToString());
        }

        private void shower_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string s in arrOfAdresses)
                MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well simple:

You are using the `LoadCompleted` to populate `arrOfAdresses`. Calling navigate does **not** guarantee `LoadCompleted` to be called! `LoadCompleted` is called - as the name suggests - as soon as the page you navigated to is loaded.

Since you navigate to two different urls **immediately after each other**, only the **last** call to `Navigate` will actually cause a website to be loaded - the prior navigations are implicitly "aborted" by the next call to `Navigate`.

So the only website that is loaded successfully (and therefore raises `LoadCompleted`) is `http://www.google.com`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. And is there some way I can show google website and after that yahoo website?

Comment: what is the exact behaviour you want? wait for google to be loaded and then navigate to yahoo (or rather the other way round like in your list)? what would be the purpose of automatically navigating to another site after the first one has loaded? :D

Comment: I want to Navigate on Yahoo, save the adress and the same thing do with google. Purpose is, that I want to navigate on page, where I get data(for example through mshtml I get name of somebody).When I get the data I want to show through MessageBox.

Comment: oh okay, although I am not really sure if I get the purpose right: you want to extract data from each page? oooh maybe you want to see if for example someone is currently logged in at google by looking at the website?

Comment: Yes, or I visit Facebook´s profile, where I will want to get number of photos and after that I should show Name and Number of Photos. But problem is in list. I want to have for example 10 profiles and I want to load each of them.

Comment: oh okay, you do **not** wanna do that using a browser! What you want is far from trivial (and would exceed a stackoverflow-question), I recommend reading about the classes the .Net framework provides for network operations: `WebClient`, `HttpWebRequest`, etc.    With these you can **directly** perform the operations you want (much easier than abusing a browser control!). There is lots of information about processing websites in the way you want - if you encounter specific problems, ask here of course ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it. Once more, thank you for your time.